# Electromagnetic induction - How is the polarity of an uncoiled wire determined?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Using the right-hand rule, we can determine the solenoid's polarity. So when we move a magnet towards a solenoid devoid of a current, the current flows so as to make the nearest side of the solenoid repel the magnet (because the field of a current always acts against the field inducing it). I understand how this works with solenoids, but this also seems to work with non-solenoid wires!

[image]

Take the diagram I drew up here. Since I haven't experimented this out, I just assumed it this way. Does it make sense that the current (and the resultant field of the wire) is induced this way if the bar magnet's N-pole is moved downwards relative to the wire? Yes or no, explain how the polarity is determined in the wire? Because the resulting current would depend on it? Where is the "N-pole" of the wire?

Comment: Is the pink coloured circular arrow around the current carrying wire, the magnetic field due to it? If yes, I think it's exactly in the opposite direction of what it's intended to be as per the right hand thumb rule.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The magnetic field is a solenoidal vector field, thus its force lines do not have the beginning and the ending.

Regarding the magnets, their magnetic force lines are closed inside them. The magnetic poles of the magnet are the areas where these lines densely exit this object. The same is valid for solenoid as it is an electric magnet.

Strait-forward current (in a wire) produces just a circular magnetic field around itself (no matter how this current is generated). Thus, it's quite difficult to select any area where the magnetic field lines leave the wire more densely. Thus, I would say that an isolated wire doesn't have magnetic pole.

Comment: Good try, but this doesn't exactly answer my doubts.